# Why do acronyms made with the acro package not appear correctly when they are first called in table captions?

Tags: tables, captions, acronyms, acro

I am using the `acro` package to handle the acronyms in my text. When using the `\ac{}` command to call up an acronym for the first time, it is expected that the acronym will be printed in "**long form (short form)**" for example "**analysis of variance (ANOVA)**". But when the acronym is called up for the first time in a table caption, the printing is not as expected for the first call.

I know there is the `\acf{}` command, but I find it very cumbersome to have to go through the entire document to find tables where an acronym was first called up.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

If there is a package that better handles acronyms, I also welcome suggestions.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{ANO}{
short=ANOVA,
long=analysis of variance
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{\ac{ANO}~---~Expected analysis of variance (ANOVA)}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]